# SetInterval, can't assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, setinterval

My code is like this:

```
$(

    function(){
        $("#btn").click(
        function()
        {
            var check_timer = setInterval(
                function(){
                    console.log("here");
                    ...
                },
                1000
            );

            setTimeout(
                function(){
                    console.log("set timeout");
                },
                5000
            );

            clearInterval(check_timer);
        });
    }

)
```

so here is the question, the script won't execute the function I defined in the setInterval function, unless I remove the "var check_timer", it works fine like this:

```
setInterval(
    function(){
        console.log("here");
        ...
    },
    1000
);
```

since I want to stop the job after some time, I use a clearInterval function, so I need to get the timer started by setInterval, how to fix this?

Comment: You immediately clear the interval you've set...

Comment: When do you want to remove the interval ? What you try to do isn't clear.

Comment: It doesn't work because you clear interval before they running. Put clearinterval into timeout or callback.

Comment: Put the clearInterval(check_timer) inside the setTimeout and you'll see it will continue for 5 seconds

Comment: owned by javascript's async nature^^

Comment: thanks guys, now I know what the problem is...totally a rookie of javascript.. @ destroy @Christoph @ FUserThrowError @ Anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not execute the function becouse you clear interval before running. When you put a `setTimeout` code is not "pausing". Code will continue execution and just after the timeout passes will execute and the code in `setTimeout`

Try:

```
$(
    function(){
        $("#btn").click(
        function()
        {
            var check_timer = setInterval(
                function(){
                    console.log("here");
                    ...
                },
                1000
            );

            /*...*/

            // instead of directly clearing the timeout
            setTimeout(
                function(){
                     // clear it after a certain amount of time
                     clearInterval(check_timer);
                },
                5000
            );

        });
    }
)
```